# Java exception ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
    JButton[][] boutons = {{btn},{btn}};

    public Fenetre() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        for (int ligne=1;ligne<=9;ligne++) {
            for(int colone=1;colone<=9;colone++) {
                //btn = new JButton();
                contentPane.add(boutons[ligne][colone]);
                btn.setName(String.valueOf(ligne) + "" + String.valueOf(colone));
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(ligne) + "" + String.valueOf(colone));
                btn.addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
```

What does my error come from ? I don't find the cause of my exception, please help me

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but would guess that valid 9 element array indexes are from 0 to 8.

Comment: Please give me a code of the corrected line

Comment: `for (int ligne=0;ligne<=8;ligne++) {
            for(int colone=0;colone<=8;colone++) {`

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing `boutons` out of bounds.

`boutons` is two dimensional array of size 2x1 so only valid indices are:

`boutons[0][0]` and `boutons[1][0]`

and you iterate [1..9][1..9] for `boutons[ligne][colone]`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
 for (int ligne=1;ligne<=9;ligne++) {
```

in an array that is not containing so much elements..

```
 JButton[][] boutons = {{btn},{btn}};
```

you need to loop in the for according to the lenght of the boutons array..

```
JButton[][] boutons = {{btn},{btn}};
```